# phinx "The --configuration option does not exist."

Tags: php, configuration, migration, phinx

Did something happen to the phinx `--configuration` option? 
A project at my work relies on it.

> [phinx docs](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/configuration.html):
>   If a `--configuration` command line option is given, Phinx will load the specified file. Otherwise, ...

however when I run:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phinx --configuration=my_config.php

  The "--configuration" option does not exist.
```

Also `--version` is not returning a version number.

```
Phinx by CakePHP - https://phinx.org.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding a `migrate` to the script fixed the issue and now it runs fine.

```
../vendor/bin/phinx migrate --configuration=my_config.php
```

I am guessing that at some point it assumed that if you ran it without the migrate 
that you wanted to migrate still allowed you to pass in options for it.